# Problems with characters remaining when unchecked

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

This is a builder-type site where invitations are completed when a customer enters a form.
There is a part where the customer put a typography, and even if I uncheck it, the text(typography) remains on the result screen.
Which part should I modify?

```
<div>
            <input
                id="typography-enable"
                type="checkbox"
                bind:checked={enableTypography}
                on:change={() => {
                    payload.typography = enableTypography ? {} : undefined;
                }}
            />
            <label for="typography-enable">메인 사진에 문구를 추가합니다.</label>
        </div>
        {#if enableTypography && typeof payload.typography !== "undefined"}
            <FlexTableLayout class="my-3" name="문구">
                <div>
                    <div class="mb-1">
                        <input
                            id="typography-content"
                            type="text"
                            maxlength={30}
                            bind:value={payload.typography.content}
                        />
                    </div>
```

Comment: It's hard to say from the code in your question exactly what might be wrong. Could you create a [minimal, reproducible example in the REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/hello-world?version=3.55.0) so we can debug it?

Comment: Try to add ```{#key payload.typography}``` just before your ```{#if}``` block